# In SSMS 2k8 r2 - the task for "Register as Data-tier application" is disabled?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm right clicking my database in SSMS 2k8 R2 and trying to select "Tasks > Register as Data-tier application" - but the option is disabled.

Has anybody else encountered this and been able to make the option available?

Comment: oops, it was because I had previously registered the database as a DAC (as visible in Management > Data-tier Applications) and forgotten

Answer (score 0):

oops, it was because I had previously registered the database as a DAC (as visible in Management